# How do you slideToggle a div if a link has a class activated?

Tags: jquery, css, class

I know... it's a bit confusing....

So I have:

```
   $("div nav ul li a").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("red");
   });
```

and my question is, how do you **slideToggle** a div if class IS "red" on "div nav ul li a"??

```
   $("div nav ul li a").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("red");
   if (........... here?
    });
```

My div...

```
   <div id="popout" style="display:none"></div>
```

I can't figure it out... help!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div nav ul li a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.toggleClass('red');
    if ($this.hasClass('red')) {
        // do your thing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the hasClass function ala:

```
if( $("div nav ul li a").hasClass('red') ){
...
}
```

Comment: Where do i place the if statement though?